# python image to pixel conversion performance

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, image-processing, scipy

I am trying to convert jpeg to pixels after resizing it. The program works pretty well with fewer images. When I tried this with more number of images (say 10k) it runs for 2 to 3 hours. Is there a way to improve the performance?

```
import os as s
import numpy as np
import scipy
from PIL import Image
from scipy import ndimage
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
def imaget_to_pxl(path,size):
    img_to_pxls=np.zeros(shape=(1,size*size*3))
    img_name={'name':0}
    N=1
    #print img_to_pxls.shape
    for i in s.listdir(path):
        if i.endswith('.jpg'):
            new_size=(size,size)
            im = Image.open(path+i, 'r')#.resize(new_size)
            pixel_values = list(im.getdata())
            if im.mode == 'RGB':
                my_image = scipy.misc.imresize(im, size=new_size)#.reshape((1,-1))
                img_to_pxls=np.concatenate((img_to_pxls,my_image.reshape((1,-1))))

    return img_to_pxls
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you try to build a numpy-array which is growing in each iteration. That's something you should avoid at all costs!

```
img_to_pxls=np.zeros(shape=(1,size*size*3))
    # later loop
    my_image = scipy.misc.imresize(im, size=new_size)#.reshape((1,-1))
    img_to_pxls=np.concatenate((img_to_pxls,my_image.reshape((1,-1))))  # !
```

Be aware, that resizing a numpy-array effects in allocating a new array (increased size) and copy all values! This will happen in each iteration with bigger and bigger arrays.

Make `img_to_pxls` a python-list (which behaves different!), append new entries and build a numpy-array once when you collected all images.

Something like (untested):

```
img_to_pxls = []
...
    my_image = scipy.misc.imresize(im, size=new_size)#.reshape((1,-1))
    img_to_pxls.append(my_image)
...
return np.array(img_to_pxls)
```

And always use some profiling tool to check for slow parts in your code before trying to optimize anything. Using for example `line_profiler` you would have found this bottleneck immediately.

Comment: thanks for the explanation and solution.It worked !!!.As you said ,when i limited images to 2k there was no much difference, when i used 5k  i observed clear difference.Thanks Again



one question:iam very much new to python,just wondering how long would it take to get such a deep understanding(if that is basic you might got to know how bad iam at python) would you mind suggesting books/refrences

Comment: @ulab In this case it's just about a basic understanding of data-structures (contiguous-array; it helps if someone did some C/C++ before) and reading the relevant docs (what is a python list, what is a numpy-array). Not sure what the best approach is to learn this. Of course following popular Stackoverflow-questions in some domain can't hurt (many interesting numpy-questions for example).